# Handling dead-letter queue message-broker independent way

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, messagebroker, dead-letter

I have a project that currently uses Spring Cloud Streams and RabbitMQ underneath. I've implemented a logic [based on the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.1.0.RC3/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_republishtodlqtrue). See below:

```java
@Component
public class ReRouteDlq {

    private static final String ORIGINAL_QUEUE = "so8400in.so8400";

    private static final String DLQ = ORIGINAL_QUEUE + ".dlq";

    private static final String PARKING_LOT = ORIGINAL_QUEUE + ".parkingLot";

    private static final String X_RETRIES_HEADER = "x-retries";

    private static final String X_ORIGINAL_EXCHANGE_HEADER = RepublishMessageRecoverer.X_ORIGINAL_EXCHANGE;

    private static final String X_ORIGINAL_ROUTING_KEY_HEADER = RepublishMessageRecoverer.X_ORIGINAL_ROUTING_KEY;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @RabbitListener(queues = DLQ)
    public void rePublish(Message failedMessage) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = failedMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        Integer retriesHeader = (Integer) headers.get(X_RETRIES_HEADER);
        if (retriesHeader == null) {
            retriesHeader = Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
        if (retriesHeader < 3) {
            headers.put(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retriesHeader + 1);
            String exchange = (String) headers.get(X_ORIGINAL_EXCHANGE_HEADER);
            String originalRoutingKey = (String) headers.get(X_ORIGINAL_ROUTING_KEY_HEADER);
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(exchange, originalRoutingKey, failedMessage);
        }
        else {
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(PARKING_LOT, failedMessage);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue parkingLot() {
        return new Queue(PARKING_LOT);
    }

}
```

It does what it is expected, however, it is binded to RabbitMQ, and my company is planning to stop using this message broker in one year or two (don't know why, must be some crazy business). So, I want to implement the same thing, but detach it from any message broker.

I tried changing the `rePublish` method this way, but it does not work:

```java
    @StreamListener(Sync.DLQ)
    public void rePublish(Message failedMessage) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = failedMessage.getHeaders();
        Integer retriesHeader = (Integer) headers.get(X_RETRIES_HEADER);
        if (retriesHeader == null) {
            retriesHeader = Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
        if (retriesHeader < 3) {
            headers.put(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retriesHeader + 1);
            String exchange = (String) headers.get(X_ORIGINAL_EXCHANGE_HEADER);
            String originalRoutingKey = (String) headers.get(X_ORIGINAL_ROUTING_KEY_HEADER);
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(exchange, originalRoutingKey, failedMessage);
        }
        else {
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(PARKING_LOT, failedMessage);
        }
    }
```

It fails because the `Message` class has immutable Headers - throws exception on the `put` attempt saying you can't change its values (uses `org.springframework.messaging.Message` class).

Is there a way to implement this dead-letter queue handler in a message broker independent way?

Comment: This is still tied to RabbitMQ via the `rabbitTemplate`; the message here is a `spring-messaging` `Message<?>` and you can send it to an output binding. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
    .setHeader("foo", "bar")
     ...
    .build();
```

Note that the message in `@StreamListener` is a spring-messaging `Message<?>`, not a spring-amqp `Message` and can't be sent using the template that way; you need an output binding to send the message to.

Comment: Thanks for the input... Quick question - I believe this would create a new message. Wouldn't it mess around with old default header information (like timestamp, for instance)?

Comment: The other headers (except `ID` and `TIMESTAMP`) are copied. If you need to retain the timestamp you can copy it to another header. The timestamp will change anyway if the binder has to perform any message conversion on the payload.